# Baofeng UV-9R Software Trouble

Tags: baofeng, software, chirp

I have CHIRP daily-20220103
It works great on my Baofeng BF-F8HP.
When I load the Baofeng UV-9R I cannot go to the settings tab. I can get to the memories tab just fine.
I decided to load the software that came with the radio and the disc has a crack in it. I can't find a good location to download it.
Would like to change the display to NAME, but the manual says it can only be done with the software.
Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to this site! So, another version of Chirp is also on the cracked disk that came with the UV-9R?

Comment: Cracked CDs will often work OK - if it's just one radial crack, and it's "stable" and doesn't slip apart. Some crazy glue / superglue might help stabilise it. No worse than a bad scratch.